# MySQL lookup from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project to add statistics for pageviews. I'm having trouble looking up and then storing in MySQL from PHP.

I have users stored in the database as:

```
ID   Email_Address      Visits
1    email@address.com  NULL
2    email@address.com  NULL
```

A variable is passed into the page called $ID which refers to which user has been visited.

Firstly, should the Visits column be a default of 0 rather than NULL?

Secondly, What query can I then use to go something like;

Lookup $ID, add 1 to Visits in that row. ie: Visits = Visits + 1?
Also if $ID is blank, it shouldn't do anything.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be default of `0`.

```
UPDATE `your-table` 
   SET `Visits` = `Visits` + 1
 WHERE `ID` = :id
```

If the `id` is blank, don't run the query.

Comment: @DT85 I'd probably use `( ! empty($id))`.

Comment: Great! Now how do I use that in the above code? :) Is that like an IF statement? Sorry, haven't used empty before.

Comment: would I go something like: `IF ( ! empty($id)) {"insert code above here"};`

Comment: @DT85 That's it, but I'd lowercase the `IF` and no trailing semi-colon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `views` column should probably default to zero.

Secondly, this is the query you should use:

```
update tablename set visits=visits+1 where id=:id
```

Replace `tablename` with the name of your table and bind the value of `:id` to the ID. (You are using prepared statements, right?) Also, if the ID is empty, just don't issue the query.

Comment: Thanks! So can I go: IF ($ID!='') ?

Comment: @DT85: Yes. PHP also comes with an [`empty` function](http://www.php.net/function.empty), as well.

Comment: Great. Just seeing how to use it re: comments by @alex below. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

1) It really depends what you are trying to do. But, from what it looks like, I would default to 0 since it looks like a numeric field.

2) I don't want to write code for you, but I'll give you some links:

First you need to [Select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp). Then add use the built in [mysql PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) to add to views, then [Update](http:////www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). Or you can do it all in one query. But, for beginners, I always advocate doing it in steps.

It also looks like ID is your primary key, which you shouldn't leave blank. Read about primary keys [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp).

Comment: No worries. although I think I misunderstood one of your comments. I'll edit my post.